Issue: StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
I try to serve model on TFserver through docker tensorflow/serving:2.16.1 and got this issue:
`<_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
details = "Could not find variable sequential_1/conv1d_2/kernel. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status error message=Resource localhost/sequential_1/conv1d_2/kernel/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
[[{{function_node __inference_serving_default_2548}}{{node sequential_1_1/conv1d_2_1/convolution/ExpandDims_1/ReadVariableOp}}]]"
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"Could not find variable sequential_1/conv1d_2/kernel. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status error message=Resource localhost/sequential_1/conv1d_2/kernel/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.\n\t [[{{function_node __inference_serving_default_2548}}{{node sequential_1_1/conv1d_2_1/convolution/ExpandDims_1/ReadVariableOp}}]]", grpc_status:9, created_time:"2024-06-20T17:42:59.542975585+07:00"}"

`

Environment:

Ubuntu 22.04
Docker version 26.1.4

Here is my model:
cnn_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu',
                                         input_shape=(input_shape, 1), data_format="channels_last", ))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, padding='valid', activation='relu'))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
 cnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

Inference code:
from preprocessing import preprocess_data
import tensorflow as tf
import grpc
# from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score
import numpy as np
# import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

from tensorflow.core.framework.tensor_pb2 import TensorProto
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2_grpc

# os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
# tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')

channel = grpc.insecure_channel("172.17.0.2:9000")
# check connection
grpc.channel_ready_future(channel).result(timeout=10)
print("Connected to gRPC server")

stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)

request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
# model_name
request.model_spec.name = "qrs"
# signature name, default is `serving_default`
request.model_spec.signature_name = "serving_default"

def grpc_infer(imgs):
    print(imgs.shape)
    # Create the TensorProto object
    tensor_proto = tf.make_tensor_proto(
        imgs,
        dtype=tf.float32,
        shape=imgs.shape
    )

    # Copy it into the request
    request.inputs["inputs"].CopyFrom(tensor_proto)

    try:
        result = stub.Predict(request, 30.0)
        result = result.outputs["output_0"]

        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

MITDB_DIR = '/home/tien/Documents/ITR/mit-bih-arrhythmia-database-1.0.0/'
test_data, _ = preprocess_data(MITDB_DIR+'100.hea')
# print(test_data[:3,:,:].shape)
y_pred = grpc_infer(test_data[:1,:,:])

